# JPA: Share one column among multiple FK mappings

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys, multiple-columns, shared

How can I share a column between two FKs to the same reference table?
I have four entities: Player,Team, TeamPlayer and PlayerScore.

Now here is the use case:

Every *batsman* in cricket (sorry for a non-global example) playing for a specific team will be scoring when he has a partner-batsman called the *runner*. Now, the *PlayerScore* entity needs to capture this information. 
So, I must ensure that both the batsman and his partner are playing for the same team. I can use this table to understand which pairs of batsman have been the performing the best. In exact terms, I need two references from PlayerScore Entity to the TeamPlayer entity. Both of them share exactly one column, team. How can I achieve this?

Here are the four classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="team")
public class Team {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name",length=50)
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="player")
public class Player {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name",length=50)
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="team_player")
public class TeamPlayer {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TeamPlayerPK id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Player.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="player")
    private Player player;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Team.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="team")
    private Team team;

    @Column(name="name",length=50)
    private String name;

@Embeddable
public static class TeamPlayerPK implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int team;
    private int player;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name="player_score")
public class PlayerScore {

    @Id
    private int scoreId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=TeamPlayer.class)
    @JoinColumns(value={@JoinColumn(name="team",referencedColumnName="team"),@JoinColumn(name="batsmen",referencedColumnName="player")})
    private TeamPlayer batsman;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=TeamPlayer.class)
    @JoinColumns(value={@JoinColumn(name="team",referencedColumnName="team"),@JoinColumn(name="runner",referencedColumnName="player")})
    private TeamPlayer runner;

    private int score;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date matchDate;

}
```

EDIT 1: Added the Mysql WB model as suggested in the comment

EDIT 2: First unsuccessful attempt:

The Team, and Player entities remain as above. But the TeamPlayer has been changed as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Player.class)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="player",referencedColumnName="id")
private Player player;
```

The @JoinColumn has been changed to @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

The annotations for runner field in the PlayerScore entity is changed as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=TeamPlayer.class)
@JoinColumns(value={@JoinColumn(name="team",referencedColumnName="team",insertable=false,updatable=false),@JoinColumn(name="runner",referencedColumnName="player",insertable=true,updatable=true)})
private TeamPlayer runner;
```

The expectation is that the FK reference for runner is also generated. THe code compiles and Eclipselink goes thru the generation but the foreign key for runner is NOT generated. In search of success yet...

[image]

Comment: Rather than jumping into the Java code, it might be helpful if you post the table structure.  Perhaps your current design could be improved.

Comment: Added the Datamodel

Comment: Also, is there any way to attach foreign keys beyond what can be generated by the metadata definition? Say, an annotation that allows me to create the above extra relation without having to add a post-create script to the persistence xml?

Comment: Why are you not having teamplayer PK (teamid, playerid) and playerscore FKs (teamid, batsman) & (teamid, runner) to it? Google re jpa "composite" PKs/FKs. PS When you edit your question, don't record a history of changes, just ask your question clearly. If that would invalidate answers then ask a new question.

Comment: THanks again. I was referring here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995681/jpa-using-composite-pks-and-fks-and-defining-relationships

How do I adapt this if I were dealing with BookPk and LanguagePk are primary keys? @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn does not allow me to add the insertable.updateable flags.